# Logs are getting truncated and showing this " Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace" in weblogic console?

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic, log4j2, weblogic12c

I am using WebLogic Console to see logs but my logs are truncated and showing this message

> Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

How to show logs for exception stacktrace without truncating. For logs, I am using log4j2.xml file configuration.

Please refer the below screenshot and Code.
Anyone please give me a solution or suggestion.

```
public void printStackTrace(int level, Throwable e) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream ops = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops);
    e.printStackTrace(ps);
    logger.error(e);
}
```

[image]

Comment: That is done to not flood the console. If you want the details, check the log files. However, I think "why" is not actually the question you wanted to ask. Please rephrase your question so it is clear what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the stack trace depth is set to 5 lines, only for stdout.
You can update this parameter in the admin console for instance : Servers//logging/Advanced, parameter "stdout Stack Trace Depth"
Set it to -1 to see complete stack traces.

Comment: Works fine but it makes out of memory exception